# Why my .current does not set default value for combobox even I have used a class to initialize?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window showing a tree view of multiple records fetched from MySql server. I was hoping to show another pop-up window with entries and comboboxes  ,and have their default values set by the information of the record that was selected on.

The problem is that it does not display anything instead the boxes are left with blanks

I have tried to set the `textvariable=var.get()`, but this makes the combobox unable to change values and collect the users' input.

I have also tried to use a class:

```
class Application:

    def __init__(self, parent, vars, pos_x, pos_y, to_test, width):
        self.parent = parent
        self.vars = vars
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.to_test = to_test
        self.width = width
        self.combo()

    def combo(self):
        self.box_value = tk.StringVar()
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, width=self.width, 
                                textvariable=self.box_value)
        self.box['values'] = self.vars
        for i in range(len(self.vars)):
            if not self.to_test == 'None':
                if self.vars[i] == self.to_test:
                    self.box.current(i)
        self.box.place(x=self.pos_x, y=self.pos_y)

#I have the function edit_tree called in a button of a previous window win
#The tree is the tree view displayed in the previous window
def edit_tree(win, tree):
    selected = tree.selection()
    edit_vendor_window = tk.Toplevel(win)
    edit_vendor_window.geometry('600x570')
    tk.Label(edit_vendor_window, text='Report Date:').place(x=10, y=10)

    vars = ('2018', '2019')
    Application(edit_vendor_window, vars, 150, 10, tree.item(selected, 
                'values)[0], 5)
```

I saw in some other answers that the problem is `StringVar` is getting garbage collected, and the solution is to use a class. But it does not work for me. This stuff just drove me crazy. Please help me out.

Comment: You don't really need to use a `StringVar`. Have you tried printing out your information of the records before inserting into the `Combobox`?

Comment: I have, the information can be printed out perfectly.

Comment: Does `tree.item(selected,values)[0]` also print out the result you want?

Comment: Yes it does! That was exactly what I want to insert into my combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.vars[i]` and `self.to_test` might not be of the same type, so your for loop never reach the comparison part. Try cast both into `Str` and also remove the `textvariable` parameter in your `Combobox`.

```
def combo(self):
    self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, width=self.width)
    self.box['values'] = self.vars
    for i in range(len(self.vars)):
        if not self.to_test == 'None':
            if str(self.vars[i]) == str(self.to_test):
                self.box.current(i)
    self.box.place(x=self.pos_x, y=self.pos_y)
```

Comment: I have added a line `print('Test!')` after `self.box.current` to see if the comparison is reached, and it got printed out. So that might not be the problem...

Comment: Did you remove the `textvariable` part?

Comment: It worked after I removed it! But how am I supposed to fetch the value that user wish to change in the combobox?

Comment: Use `self.box.get()`.